Unable to mock getSignedUrl of npm module "@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer" using jest
I was trying to mock the npm module "@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer"'s function getSignedUrl using jest.
Here is the implementation:
import { getSignedUrl } from '@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer'
let url = 'test value', // confidential
keyPairId = 'test value',  // confidential
dateLessThan = 'test value',
privateKey = 'test value'; // confidential

const signedUrl = getSignedUrl({
  url,
  keyPairId,
  dateLessThan,
  privateKey,
})

This is how I'm trying to mock it:
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer', () => {
  return {
    getSignedUrl: jest.fn(() => 'test'),
  }
})

Another approach:
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer', () => ({
  getSignedUrl: jest.fn(() => {
    console.log('test mock')
    return 'test'
  }),
}))

Another approach:
jest
  .spyOn(cloudfrontSigner, 'getSignedUrl')
  .mockImplementation(() => 'test url')

Another approach:
import * as cloudfrontSigner from '@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer'

Object.defineProperty(cloudfrontSigner, {
  getSignedUrl: jest.fn(),
})

Another approach:
import * as cloudfrontSigner from '@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer'

cloudfrontSigner.getSignedUrl = jest.fn()

Also, I tried another module called rewire
import rewire from 'rewire'
const mockGetSignedUrl = jest.fn()
mockGetSignedUrl.mockReturnValue('test url')

cloudfrontSignerRewired.__set__('getSignedUrl', mockGetSignedUrl)

Tried implementing the aws-sdk-mock
import AWS from 'aws-sdk-mock'
AWS.mock('CloudFront.Signer', 'getSignedUrl', 'zameer test')

AWS.mock('CloudFront.Signer', 'getSignedUrl', function (params, callback) {
  console.log('test test 123')
  callback(null, { Item: { Key: 'Value' } })
})

Another approach:
jest.mock('@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer', () => {
  const cloudfrontSigner = jest.requireActual('@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer');

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...cloudfrontSigner,
    getSignedUrl: jest.mockImplementation(()=> {
      console.log("this is mock")
      return 'test url'}),
  };
});

Another approach:
import * as cloudfrontSigner from '@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer'

cloudfrontSigner.getSignedUrl.mockImplementation(()=>'test')

Using spy:
import * as cloudfrontSigner from '@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer'

const getSignedUrlSpy = jest.spyOn(cloudfrontSigner, 'getSignedUrl').mockReturnValueOnce('test');

When I execute the test cases, getSignedUrl is never mocked. Seems like none of the above approaches are working. Need help here please.

Add a module mapping in the jest configuration like this:
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "@aws-sdk/cloudfront-signer": "<rootDir>/tests/_mocks_/getSignedUrl",
},

Add a file <rootDir>/tests/_mocks_/getSignedUrl.mjs with a dummy function:
export function getSignedUrl(params) {
  console.log('Calling from mocked getSignedUrl')
}

